# Android- Display Global Application Information

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I am working on an application that has several states that matter to the user, online vs offline, how far out of date the local application database is, et cetera.  I understand that both non-persistent and persistent notifications are available in android, and might be appropriate in this scenario. However, in our organization's iOS application, there is an 'information bar'.

[image: Application Sketch]

I realize that this is somewhat of a departure from material design.  Is this even possible?  I'd like to extend the App Bar in some way as opposed to creating a fragment that I add to every activity if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of the following

1) Replace the action bar with toolbar and customize the design on your own and handle it.

2) Create the separate layout file with the above design and then include it in any screen using the tag `<include/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a custom Toolbar class or with Fragments. For the later option, each activity will have the user information at the top, either as a view or a fragment. The "normal app stuff" will be a FrameLayout which can hold one fragment at a time. See the Fragment tutorials on http://developer.android.com.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but saying "Use a custom toolbar" and linking to the android documentation is not particularly helpful

Comment: @SamBorick Note that I have given two suggestions. I expect you to do some research to find out which is better suited for your needs. A quick google search for "android toolbar" and "android fragment" will give you several hits. I'm just suggesting you look at the tutorials on the official Android developer site rather than some random blogs. I also don't feel like taking the time to get the direct link since you can easily find it yourself with a few seconds work.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really hooks for extending the toolbar-  in fact Google has deprecated a lot of stuff it used to be able to do (such as tabs in the toolbar).  Your best bet is to use a custom fragment at the top of every Activity.

Comment: With the newish Toolbar, you can do a lot more customization than with the old ActionBar.